# Installed latest patch, now Oracle.DataAccess.dll is throwing Data provider internal error(-3000)

Tags: oracle, installation, odp.net

The latest Oracle patch: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/security-advisory/cpujul2017-3236622.html has been installed on the server running version 12.1.0.2.0.

We have .Net applications running directly on the same machine which uses the Oracle.DataAccess.dll which was at version 2.121.2.0 but the patch seems to have upgraded this to version 2.121.2.0 RELEASE 4 like so:

[image]

and now we get which appears to be a generic error:

> Data provider internal error(-3000) [System.String]
>
> OracleException (0x80004005): Data provider internal error(-3000) [System.String]]
>      Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable) +1909
>      Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src) +53
>      Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open() +5393
>      NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection() +134
>      NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.OpenConnection() +65

Any ideas where I can even start to look? I am suspecting version mismatch but I can't understand why that would happen.

Comment: Did you go through this thread? https://community.oracle.com/thread/3998555

Comment: I think I've gone though every article I could find on Google. With that article above I don't think it's a 32bit/64bit problem. Everything is 64bit.